# C# random math questions project

Tags: c#, beginner, console, mathematics

I made a C# console math project where the user answers addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, power or square-root questions based on the difficulty they choose!

However, I am struggling to refactor one part of my code.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace mathstester
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum UserDifficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Normal,
            Hard
        }

        public enum MathOperation
        {
            Addition = 1,
            Subtraction = 2,
            Multiplication = 3,
            Division = 4,
            Power = 5,
            SquareRoot = 6
        }
        public static (int operationMin, int operationMax) GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {

            switch (userDifficulty)
            {
                case UserDifficulty.Easy:
                    return (1, 4);
                case UserDifficulty.Normal:
                    return (1, 5);
                case UserDifficulty.Hard:
                    return (3, 7);
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        public static (string message, double correctAnswer) GetMathsEquation(MathOperation mathOperation, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {

            int number1;
            int number2;
            Random randomNumber = new Random();

            switch (mathOperation)
            {
                case MathOperation.Addition:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} + {number2}", number1 + number2);
                case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} - {number2}", number1 - number2);
                case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                    number1 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? randomNumber.Next(13) : randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    number2 = userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy ? randomNumber.Next(13) : randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} * {number2}", number1 * number2);
                case MathOperation.Division:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(10000);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"{number1} / {number2}", number1 / (double)number2);
                case MathOperation.Power:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(13);
                    number2 = randomNumber.Next(5);
                    return ($"{number1} ^ {number2}", Math.Pow(number1, number2));
                case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                    number1 = randomNumber.Next(1000);
                    return ($"√{number1}", Math.Sqrt(number1));
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public class OperationQuestionScore
        {
            public int AdditionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int AdditionScore { get; set; }
            public int SubtractionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int SubtractionScore { get; set; }
            public int MultiplicationQuestion { get; set; }
            public int MultiplicationScore { get; set; }
            public int DivisionQuestion { get; set; }
            public int DivisionScore { get; set; }
            public int PowerQuestion { get; set; }
            public int PowerScore { get; set; }
            public int SquareRootQuestion { get; set; }
            public int SquareRootScore { get; set; }
        }

        public static OperationQuestionScore Score()
        {
            return new OperationQuestionScore();
        }

        public static (int, OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
        {
            int totalScore = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(userDifficulty);
            var score = Score();
            var question = Score();
            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
            {
                int mathRandomOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
                MathOperation mathOperation = (MathOperation)mathRandomOperation;
                var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
                if (mathRandomOperation == 4 || mathRandomOperation == 6)
                {
                    Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
                }
                double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                    switch (mathOperation)
                    {
                        case MathOperation.Addition:
                            question.AdditionQuestion++;
                            score.AdditionScore++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                            question.SubtractionQuestion++;
                            score.SubtractionScore++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                            question.MultiplicationQuestion++;
                            score.MultiplicationScore++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Division:
                            question.DivisionQuestion++;
                            score.DivisionScore++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Power:
                            question.PowerQuestion++;
                            score.PowerScore++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                            question.SquareRootQuestion++;
                            score.SquareRootScore++;
                            break;
                    }
                    totalScore++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    switch (mathOperation)
                    {
                        case MathOperation.Addition:
                            question.AdditionQuestion++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                            question.SubtractionQuestion++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                            question.MultiplicationQuestion++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Division:
                            question.DivisionQuestion++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.Power:
                            question.PowerQuestion++;
                            break;
                        case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                            question.SquareRootQuestion++;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
            }
            return (totalScore, score, question);
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, UserDifficulty> difficultyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, UserDifficulty>();
            difficultyDictionary.Add("E", UserDifficulty.Easy);
            difficultyDictionary.Add("N", UserDifficulty.Normal);
            difficultyDictionary.Add("H", UserDifficulty.Hard);

            string userInputDifficulty = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
                userInputDifficulty = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (userInputDifficulty != "E" && userInputDifficulty != "N" && userInputDifficulty != "H");

            UserDifficulty userDifficulty = difficultyDictionary[userInputDifficulty];

            int numberOfQuestions = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
            } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

            var (totalScore, score, question) = RunTest(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty);
            Console.WriteLine($"Total score: {totalScore} of {numberOfQuestions}");

            if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Easy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {question.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {question.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Normal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Addition score: {score.AdditionScore} of {question.AdditionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subtraction score: {score.SubtractionScore} of {question.SubtractionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Multiplication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {question.DivisionQuestion}");
            }
            else if (userDifficulty == UserDifficulty.Hard)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Multipication score: {score.MultiplicationScore} of {question.MultiplicationQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Division score: {score.DivisionScore} of {question.DivisionQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Power score: {score.PowerScore} of {question.PowerQuestion}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Squareroot score: {score.SquareRootScore} of {question.SquareRootQuestion}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my "RunTest" function I've got two "switch" statements inside an "if-else" statement.
Without changing my code too much, I want to shorten the code by using only one "switch" statement inside my "if-else" statement.

I need help refactoring my code so I don't have so many loops inside a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way that you can simplify much of this code is by building out a set of classes to represent your different operations. You can then encapsulate the rules for that operation within those classes.

To get started, you can define an abstract `Operation` class to define the shared properties and methods of the operations:

```
public abstract class Operation
{
    protected readonly Random Random = new Random();

    private readonly string _operationName;

    public Operation(string operationName, params UserDifficulty[] userDifficulties)
    {
        _operationName = operationName;
        UserDifficulties = userDifficulties;
    }

    public int Question { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public UserDifficulty[] UserDifficulties { get; }
    public string GetScoreDisplay() => $"{_operationName} score: {Score} of {Question}";
    public abstract (string message, double correctAnswer) GetMathsEquation(UserDifficulty userDifficulty);
}
```

You can then create a class for each of your different operations, and implement the base class accordingly. For example, `Addition` would look like:

```
public class Addition : Operation
{
    public Addition() : base("Addition", UserDifficulty.Easy, UserDifficulty.Normal)
    {
    }

    public override (string message, double correctAnswer) GetMathsEquation(UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
    {
        var number1 = Random.Next(1000);
        var number2 = Random.Next(1000);
        return ($"{number1} + {number2}", number1 + number2);
    }
}
```

With these all in place, you can actually remove *every* `switch` statement in your code. This is because the specific operation logic is implemented in each class. All you need to do is construct a collection of the `Operation` objects and then call the appropriate methods.

The `RunTest` would now look as follows:

```
public static (int, List<Operation>) RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
{
    int totalScore = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    var operations = new List<Operation>
    {
        new Addition(),
        new Subtraction(),
        new Multiplication(),
        new Division(),
        new Power(),
        new SquareRoot(),
    }.Where(o => o.UserDifficulties.Contains(userDifficulty)).ToList();

    while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
    {
        int randomOperation = random.Next(operations.Count);
        Operation operation = operations[randomOperation];
        var (message, correctAnswer) = operation.GetMathsEquation(userDifficulty);
        if (operation is Division || operation is SquareRoot)
        {
            Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
        }
        double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
            operation.Score++;
            totalScore++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
        }
        operation.Question++;
        numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
    }
    return (totalScore, operations);
}
```

And the usage of that method would look like:

```
var (totalScore, operations) = RunTest(numberOfQuestions, userDifficulty);
Console.WriteLine($"Total score: {totalScore} of {numberOfQuestions}");

foreach (var operation in operations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(operation.GetScoreDisplay());
}
```

---

Here's another option that achieves your goal of reducing the number of switch statements in the `RunTest` method from two to one with fewer overall code changes:

```
public static (int, OperationQuestionScore, OperationQuestionScore) RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty)
{
    int totalScore = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(userDifficulty);
    var score = Score();
    var question = Score();

    while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
    {
        int mathRandomOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
        MathOperation mathOperation = (MathOperation)mathRandomOperation;
        var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
        if (mathRandomOperation == 4 || mathRandomOperation == 6)
        {
            Console.Write($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write($"What is {message} =");
        }

        Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementQuestion;
        Action<OperationQuestionScore> incrementScore;
        switch (mathOperation)
        {
            case MathOperation.Addition:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.AdditionQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.AdditionScore++;
                break;
            case MathOperation.Subtraction:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.SubtractionQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.SubtractionScore++;
                break;
            case MathOperation.Multiplication:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.MultiplicationQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.MultiplicationScore++;
                break;
            case MathOperation.Division:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.DivisionQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.DivisionScore++;
                break;
            case MathOperation.Power:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.PowerQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.PowerScore++;
                break;
            case MathOperation.SquareRoot:
                incrementQuestion = o => o.SquareRootQuestion++;
                incrementScore = o => o.SquareRootScore++;
                break;
            default:
                incrementQuestion = _ => { };
                incrementScore = _ => { };
                break;
        }

        double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
            incrementQuestion(question);
            incrementScore(score);
            totalScore++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
            incrementQuestion(question);
        }
        numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
    }
    return (totalScore, score, question);
}
```

As you can see, a single `switch` statement now exists before the `if`/`else` block. And two `Action` delegates are being created within the switch statement to  represent the proper "increment" operation needed in the `if`/`else` block.

Comment: Thanks @devNull But Is there a way so I don't need to change my code so much?

Comment: @crazydanyal1414 I've edited my answer to include an additional option that only requires changing the code within the `RunTest` method